# Visual Studio 2017 - Disable auto-completion on Enter key press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to edit the scripts for Unity 3D Project.

In a script, I want to create a new function "Move", but I get a problem with autocomplete.

If I write "public void Move"

[image]

I get a a proposal "OnAnimatorMove", but I don't need this function!
Now, after "Move" I enter a space character " ", but my function name is then automatically replaced by "OnAnimatorMove" and the "{","}" are automatically inserted.

[image]

Same happens, if I try to insert "(" character after "Move".

How can I prevent it?

Comment: You can make autocomplete require confirmation with tab by edit -> IntelliSense -> toggle autocompletion mode or so (not using the english locale), but that will work for everything, not only one name.

Comment: can you just post a screenshot from your version of visual studio, where I can see the options for i? (my vs is in german)

Comment: There you go mate. I inlined the screenshots.

Comment: If you press the `Escape` key (`esc`), IntelliSense will close until another letter is pressed (that's not `enter`)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thx. As a workaround it is ok. Can I used autocompletion only if I pressed for example "Tab"-Key?

Comment: You can also hit ctrl-Z to undo anything intellisense does that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

U can click escape to disable the autocompletion or u can disble it all together by going to
VS > Tools > Options > Tools for unity > and under 'code edition' disable Unity massage code completion.
after that restart

Answer (score 0):

I can solve it, going to Edit->Preferences->External Tools, and in External Script Editor, select Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise)